# Apache-Ignite integration as Hibernate 2nd level cache not starting?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, caching, gridgain, ignite

I am trying to set Apache Ignite as the second level Hibernate cache provider in my project but i am getting a strange exception.

Configurations are as below:

1. POM.xml

Added

```
<spring.version>4.3.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
<hibernate.version>4.3.8.Final</hibernate.version>
<ignite.version>1.6.0</ignite.version>

<repositories>
<repository>
    <id>GridGain External Repository</id>
    <url>http://www.gridgainsystems.com/nexus/content/repositories/external</url>
</repository>
</repositories>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
        <version>${ignite.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${ignite.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>${ignite.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

2. Spring Hibernate Configuration file

   ```
   <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
   <bean id="sessionFactoryHibernate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
   <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <props>
           <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">true</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
           <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.apache.ignite.cache.hibernate.HibernateRegionFactory</prop>
           <prop key="org.apache.ignite.hibernate.grid_name">hibernate-grid</prop>
           <prop key="org.apache.ignite.hibernate.default_access_type">READ_ONLY</prop>
       </props>
   </property>
   <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.entity"></property>
   ```

   3. ignite-configuration.xml

> ```
>     <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
>        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>        xsi:schemaLocation="
>         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
>
>     <!-- Basic configuration for atomic cache. -->
>     <bean id="atomic-cache" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration" abstract="true">
>     <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
>     <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
>     <property name="writeSynchronizationMode" value="FULL_SYNC"/>
>     </bean>
>
>     <!-- Basic configuration for transactional cache. -->
>     <bean id="transactional-cache" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration" abstract="true">
>     <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
>     <property name="atomicityMode" value="TRANSACTIONAL"/>
>     <property name="writeSynchronizationMode" value="FULL_SYNC"/>
>     </bean>
>
>     <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
>     <!-- 
>         Specify the name of the caching grid (should correspond to the 
>         one in Hibernate configuration).
>     -->
>     <property name="gridName" value="hibernate-grid"/>
>
>     <!-- 
>         Specify cache configuration for each L2 cache region (which corresponds 
>         to a full class name or a full association name).
>     -->
>     <property name="cacheConfiguration">
>         <list>
>             <!--
>                 Configurations for entity caches.
>             -->
> <!--             <bean parent="transactional-cache">
>                 <property name="name" value="com.mycompany.MyEntity1"/>
>             </bean>
>             <bean parent="transactional-cache">
>                 <property name="name" value="com.mycompany.MyEntity2"/>
>             </bean>
>             <bean parent="transactional-cache">
>                 <property name="name" value="com.mycompany.MyEntity1.children"/>
>             </bean>
>   -->
>             <!-- Configuration for update timestamps cache. -->
>             <bean parent="atomic-cache">
>                 <property name="name" value="org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache"/>
>             </bean>
>
>             <!-- Configuration for query result cache. -->
>             <bean parent="atomic-cache">
>                 <property name="name" value="org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache"/>
>             </bean>
>         </list>
>     </property>
>
>     </bean>
>
>     </beans>
> ```

4. Entity Class

> ```
> import java.io.Serializable;
>
> import javax.persistence.Column;
> import javax.persistence.Entity;
> import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
> import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
> import javax.persistence.Id;
> import javax.persistence.Index;
> import javax.persistence.Table;
>
> import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
> import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;
>
> @Entity
> @Table(name = "USER_TYPE", indexes = {
>       @Index(columnList = "TYPE_SHORT_NAME", name = "TYPE_SHORT_NAME_UNIQUE_idx", unique = true), })
> @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY, region = "userType")
>
> public class UserType implements Serializable {
>
>   private static final long serialVersionUID = -628308304752474026L;
>
>   @Id
>   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
>   @Column(name = "USER_TYPE_ID")
>   private int userTypeId;
>
>   @Column(name = "TYPE_SHORT_NAME", length = 20, nullable = false)
>   private String typeShortName;
>
>   @Column(name = "TYPE_LONG_NAME", length = 255)
>   private String typeLongName;
>
>   public UserType() {
>   }
>
>   public UserType(int userTypeId, String typeShortName, String typeLongName) {
>       this.userTypeId = userTypeId;
>       this.typeShortName = typeShortName;
>       this.typeLongName = typeLongName;
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public int hashCode() {
>       final int prime = 31;
>       int result = 1;
>       result = prime * result + ((typeLongName == null) ? 0 : typeLongName.hashCode());
>       result = prime * result + ((typeShortName == null) ? 0 : typeShortName.hashCode());
>       result = prime * result + userTypeId;
>       return result;
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
>       if (this == obj)
>           return true;
>       if (obj == null)
>           return false;
>       if (!(obj instanceof UserType))
>           return false;
>       UserType other = (UserType) obj;
>       if (typeLongName == null) {
>           if (other.typeLongName != null)
>               return false;
>       } else if (!typeLongName.equals(other.typeLongName))
>           return false;
>       if (typeShortName == null) {
>           if (other.typeShortName != null)
>               return false;
>       } else if (!typeShortName.equals(other.typeShortName))
>           return false;
>       if (userTypeId != other.userTypeId)
>           return false;
>       return true;
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public String toString() {
>       return "UserType [userTypeId=" + userTypeId + ", typeShortName=" + typeShortName + ", typeLongName="
>               + typeLongName + "]";
>   }
>
>   public int getUserTypeId() {
>       return userTypeId;
>   }
>
>   public void setUserTypeId(int userTypeId) {
>       this.userTypeId = userTypeId;
>   }
>
>   public String getTypeShortName() {
>       return typeShortName;
>   }
>
>   public void setTypeShortName(String typeShortName) {
>       this.typeShortName = typeShortName;
>   }
>
>   public String getTypeLongName() {
>       return typeLongName;
>   }
>
>   public void setTypeLongName(String typeLongName) {
>       this.typeLongName = typeLongName;
>   }
>
> }
> ```

5. IgniteAlphaCachemanager

> ```
> public interface AlphaCacheManager {
> AlphaCache<?, ?> getCache(Class<?> cacheClass);
> }
>
>
>
>
>
>
> import java.util.Map;
> import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
>
> import org.apache.ignite.Ignite;
> import org.apache.ignite.IgniteCache;
> import org.apache.ignite.Ignition;
> import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
>
>
> @Repository
> public class IgniteAlphaCacheManager implements AlphaCacheManager {
>
> private final Ignite ignite;
> private final Map<Class<?>, AlphaCache<?, ?>> caches;
>
> public IgniteAlphaCacheManager() {
>   System.out.println("Init cache...");
>     ignite = Ignition.start("classpath:/spring/ignite-configuration.xml");
>     //ignite = Ignition.start();
>     caches = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
>     initCaches();
> }
>
> private void initCaches() {
>   IgniteCache<Integer, BaseIdea> igniteCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(BaseIdea.class.getName());
>   AlphaCache<Integer, BaseIdea> ideaCache = new IgniteAlphaCache<>(igniteCache);
>   caches.put(BaseIdea.class, ideaCache);
> }
>
> @Override
> public AlphaCache<?, ?> getCache(Class<?> cacheClass) {
>   return caches.get(cacheClass);
> }
>
> }
>
> }
> ```

The exception that i get it below on tomcat startup:

```
Jul 27, 2016 1:46:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateStatisticsFactoryBean': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactoryHibernate': Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactoryHibernate' defined in class path resource [spring/databaseContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cache is not started: userType; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactoryHibernate' defined in class path resource [spring/databaseContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cache is not started: userType
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:350)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:756)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4811)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5272)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactoryHibernate' defined in class path resource [spring/databaseContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cache is not started: userType
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1048)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:570)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cache is not started: userType
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.publicCache(GridCacheProcessor.java:3143)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.getCache(IgniteKernal.java:2427)
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.hibernate.HibernateRegionFactory.regionCache(HibernateRegionFactory.java:226)
    at org.apache.ignite.cache.hibernate.HibernateRegionFactory.buildEntityRegion(HibernateRegionFactory.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:364)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 35 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure caches for all your regions. For example, for `userType` you can add this to the configuration:

```
<bean parent="transactional-cache">
    <property name="name" value="userType"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks Valetin but i am already making use of annotation in userType Class.@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY, region = "userType") Are annotations not supported in ignite-cache.

Answer (score 2):

`@Cache` annotation will be executed only if you use the `entityManager.find()` method. That mean this will work only with primary keys. Another approach is to use query cache or ignite API.

Answer (score 1):

Till now, annotations not supported in ignite-cache (as l2 cache for hibernate).

If you don't want to put configuration of each entity in cache configuration, follow below steps

Step 1. Create a new class HibernateRegionFactoryForIgnite as below

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.cache.CacheException;
import org.apache.ignite.Ignition;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.CacheAtomicityMode;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.CacheMode;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.CacheWriteSynchronizationMode;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.hibernate.HibernateCollectionRegionForIgnite;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.hibernate.HibernateEntityRegionForIgnite;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.hibernate.HibernateRegionFactory;
import org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration;
import org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal;
import org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteInternalCache;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.boot.spi.SessionFactoryOptions;
import org.hibernate.cache.spi.CacheDataDescription;
import org.hibernate.cache.spi.CollectionRegion;
import org.hibernate.cache.spi.EntityRegion;
import org.hibernate.cache.spi.TimestampsRegion;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Settings;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class HibernateRegionFactoryForIgnite extends HibernateRegionFactory {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 530290669748711933L;

    public static Logger logger =     Logger.getLogger(HibernateRegionFactoryForIgnite.class);

    private IgniteKernal ignite;
    private IgniteInternalCache<Object, Object> dfltCache;
    private final Map<String, String> regionCaches = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void start(SessionFactoryOptions settings, Properties properties) throws CacheException {
        start(new Settings(settings), properties);
        initializeVariables(properties);
    }

    public void initializeVariables(Properties props) {
        ignite = (IgniteKernal) Ignition.ignite("hibernate-grid");
        String dfltCacheName = props.getProperty(DFLT_CACHE_NAME_PROPERTY);

        for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> prop : props.entrySet()) {
            String key = prop.getKey().toString();
            if (key.startsWith(REGION_CACHE_PROPERTY)) {
                String regionName = key.substring(REGION_CACHE_PROPERTY.length());
                String cacheName = prop.getValue().toString();
                regionCaches.put(regionName, cacheName);
            }
        }

        if (dfltCacheName != null) {
            dfltCache = ((IgniteKernal) ignite).getCache(dfltCacheName);
        }
    }

    private IgniteInternalCache<Object, Object> regionCache(String regionName) throws CacheException {
        String cacheName = regionCaches.get(regionName);
        if (cacheName == null) {
            if (dfltCache != null)
                return dfltCache;
            cacheName = regionName;
        }
        IgniteInternalCache<Object, Object> cache = ((IgniteKernal) ignite).getCache(cacheName);
        if (cache == null)
            throw new CacheException("Cache '" + cacheName + "' for region '" + regionName + "' is not configured.");
        return cache;
    }

    @Override
    public EntityRegion buildEntityRegion(String regionName, Properties props, CacheDataDescription metadata)
            throws CacheException {
        EntityRegion entityRegion = null;
        try {
            entityRegion = new HibernateEntityRegion(this, regionName, ignite, regionCache(regionName),
                metadata);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        if (entityRegion == null) {
            ignite.createCache(cacheConfiguration(regionName));
            try {
                entityRegion = new HibernateEntityRegion(this, regionName, ignite, regionCache(regionName),
                    metadata);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.debug("exception occurred");
            }
        }
        return entityRegion;
    }

    @Override
    public CollectionRegion buildCollectionRegion(String regionName, Properties props, CacheDataDescription metadata)
        throws CacheException {
        CollectionRegion collectionRegion = null;
        try {
            collectionRegion = new HibernateCollectionRegion(this, regionName, ignite, regionCache(regionName),
                metadata);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        if (collectionRegion == null) {
            ignite.createCache(cacheConfiguration(regionName));
            try {
                collectionRegion = new HibernateCollectionRegion(this, regionName, ignite,
                    regionCache(regionName), metadata);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.debug("exception occurred");
            }
        }
        return collectionRegion;
    }

    private CacheConfiguration<Object, Object> cacheConfiguration(String cacheName) {
        CacheConfiguration<Object, Object> cfg = new CacheConfiguration<Object, Object>();
        cfg.setName(cacheName);
        cfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
        cfg.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL);
        cfg.setWriteSynchronizationMode(CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FULL_SYNC);

        return cfg;
    }
}
```

Step 2. Use class HibernateRegionFactoryForIgnite as value for key hibernate.cache.region.factory_class in hibernate configuration properties