# Apache-Ignite integration as Hibernate 2nd level cache , does it understand annotations?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, caching, gridgain, ignite

In Continuation to 
[apache-ignite-integration-as-hibernate-2nd-level-cache-not-starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624139/apache-ignite-integration-as-hibernate-2nd-level-cache-not-starting)

I am making use of annotation

```
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY, region = "userType"
```

in my Entity:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Index;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_TYPE", indexes = {
      @Index(columnList = "TYPE_SHORT_NAME", name = "TYPE_SHORT_NAME_UNIQUE_idx", unique = true), })
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY, region = "userType")

public class UserType implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -628308304752474026L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "USER_TYPE_ID")
  private int userTypeId;

  @Column(name = "TYPE_SHORT_NAME", length = 20, nullable = false)
  private String typeShortName;

  @Column(name = "TYPE_LONG_NAME", length = 255)
  private String typeLongName;

  public UserType() {
  }

  public UserType(int userTypeId, String typeShortName, String typeLongName) {
      this.userTypeId = userTypeId;
      this.typeShortName = typeShortName;
      this.typeLongName = typeLongName;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
      final int prime = 31;
      int result = 1;
      result = prime * result + ((typeLongName == null) ? 0 : typeLongName.hashCode());
      result = prime * result + ((typeShortName == null) ? 0 : typeShortName.hashCode());
      result = prime * result + userTypeId;
      return result;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      if (this == obj)
          return true;
      if (obj == null)
          return false;
      if (!(obj instanceof UserType))
          return false;
      UserType other = (UserType) obj;
      if (typeLongName == null) {
          if (other.typeLongName != null)
              return false;
      } else if (!typeLongName.equals(other.typeLongName))
          return false;
      if (typeShortName == null) {
          if (other.typeShortName != null)
              return false;
      } else if (!typeShortName.equals(other.typeShortName))
          return false;
      if (userTypeId != other.userTypeId)
          return false;
      return true;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
      return "UserType [userTypeId=" + userTypeId + ", typeShortName=" + typeShortName + ", typeLongName="
              + typeLongName + "]";
  }

  public int getUserTypeId() {
      return userTypeId;
  }

  public void setUserTypeId(int userTypeId) {
      this.userTypeId = userTypeId;
  }

  public String getTypeShortName() {
      return typeShortName;
  }

  public void setTypeShortName(String typeShortName) {
      this.typeShortName = typeShortName;
  }

  public String getTypeLongName() {
      return typeLongName;
  }

  public void setTypeLongName(String typeLongName) {
      this.typeLongName = typeLongName;
  }

}
```

But still in need to add this in ignite-configuration.

```
<bean parent="transactional-cache">
    <property name="name" value="userType"/>
</bean>
```

Are annotations not supported in ignite-cache? 
Why do we need to implement this in ignite-configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotation works. It defines the cache region where the type should be cached, concurrency strategy and other settings, but this doesn't imply the automatic region creation. You have to explicitly configure the cache.

However, I don't see any reason why not to improve this and created an Ignite ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-3603